# jQuery Ajax call returns xhr.status = 0 and thrownError = No Transport from a JSF page

Tags: json, jquery, jsf

jQuery Ajax call returns xhr.status = 0 and thrownError = No Transport from a JSF page.

My Code :

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',            
        url : urlbcat,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
        alert("success "+data.Some_ID);
        CALLINGMETHOD(data);
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            alert("xhr: "+xhr.status);
            alert("thrownError: "+thrownError);
            alert("ajaxOptions: "+ajaxOptions);

        }   


    });
```

I see alerts showing the correct url, but xhr = 0 and thrownError = No Transport

Comment: What URL were you using? You surely didn't use a JSF URL? JSF isn't designed for listening on web service requests, for that JAX-RS or even plain vanilla servlet should be used. The `contentType` of `application/json` on a GET request isn't making any utter sense either, by the way.

Comment: Thanks Balu anyways I have figured the way out , its by declaring usage over cross platform jQuery.support.cors = true;